# Join the main Table with history table to get the current rate of the main table and the last and previous rate from the history table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

As per the part of the avoiding two different tables is there any way to combine it to a single query to get the result? Here in the history table having more than 100 rows against the currency '**USD**' I need only the last value which is move to the history to pick out

```
Select  M.CR CR, M.Rate RATE, M.Operator OPERATOR
From Rate M
Where M.CR = 'USD' 


Select M.CR CR, M.Rate RATE, M.Operator OPERATOR
    , max(M.FROMSOURCEDATE) As MovedDate
From RateHistory M
Where M.CR = 'USD' 
Group by M.CR, M.Rate, M.Operator
```

Here only `FROMSOURCEDATE` is the only field I can which is updating with date when it is moved to history table.

Current Result is

| CR | RATE | OPERATOR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USD | 3.65 | * |

| CR | RATE | OPERATOR | MOVEDDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USD | 3.75 | * | 2023-10-29 22:57:22.820 |
| USD | 3.73 | * | 2023-10-29 22:56:22.810 |
| USD | 3.67 | * | 2023-10-29 22:56:21.820 |
| USD | 3.77 | * | 2023-10-29 22:57:22.803 |
| USD | 3.55 | * | 2023-9-29 21:57:22.820 |
| USD | 3.45 | * | 2023-9-29 21:56:22.810 |
| USD | 3.71 | * | 2023-8-29 20:55:25.505 |
| USD | 3.75 | * | 2023-8-29 20:55:25.410 |
| USD | 3.66 | * | 2023-7-29 22:57:22.820 |
| USD | 3.68 | * | 2023-7-29 22:57:22.820 |
| USD | 3.75 | * | 2023-7-29 22:57:22.820 |

the needed result is as follows

| CR | NEWRATE | OLDRATE | OPERATOR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USD | 3.65 | 3.75 | * |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TOP 1 within the OUTER APPLY to get only the most recent historical rate  based on the latest FROMSOURCEDATE

```
CREATE TABLE Rate (
    CR NVARCHAR(50),
    Rate DECIMAL(10, 2),
    Operator NVARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE RateHistory (
    CR NVARCHAR(50),
    Rate DECIMAL(10, 2),
    Operator NVARCHAR(50),
    FROMSOURCEDATE DATETIME
);
```

```
INSERT INTO Rate (CR, Rate, Operator)
VALUES
('USD', 3.65, '*');

INSERT INTO RateHistory (CR, Rate, Operator, FROMSOURCEDATE)
VALUES
('USD', 3.60, '*', '2023-10-27T22:57:22.820'),
('USD', 3.75, '*', '2023-10-29T22:57:22.820'),
('USD', 3.70, '*', '2023-10-28T22:57:22.820');
```

```
SELECT
    r.CR,
    r.Rate AS NEWRATE,
    rh.Rate AS OLDRATE,
    r.Operator
FROM
    Rate r
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 Rate
    FROM RateHistory
    WHERE CR = r.CR
    ORDER BY FROMSOURCEDATE DESC
) rh
WHERE r.CR = 'USD';
```

| CR | NEWRATE | OLDRATE | Operator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USD | 3.65 | 3.75 | * |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/41TNoP7l)

Comment: The great thing about `VALUES` is that its plural... you only need a single insert for as many rows as you like.